# MVC PDF Stream Generation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, pdf

I am working on a project that requires me to concatenate a number of PDF files stored on our server, and present it in a webpage.
This PDF data will be hidden, and used to allow the user to print out multiple PDFs with a single button press.

I am currently using iframes to achieve this by pointing the frame source to the URL that handles this functionality.

This works for a single file:

```
public ActionResult PrintInvoice(string invoiceNumber)
{
    string fileloc = GetInvoiceFileLocation(invoiceNumber);
    FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileloc, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    return File(fs, "application/pdf");
}
```

This works for a single file too:

```
public ActionResult PrintInvoice(string invoiceNumber)
{
    string fileloc = GetInvoiceFileLocation(invoiceNumber);
    fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(fileloc);
    ms = new MemoryStream(fileBytes);
    return File(ms, "application/pdf");
}
```

However, this does not work (iFrame reports that the PDF cannot be read):

```
public ActionResult PrintInvoice(string invoiceNumber)
{
    string fileloc = GetInvoiceFileLocation(invoiceNumber);
    fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(fileloc);
    ms = new MemoryStream();
    ms.Write(fileBytes, 0, fileBytes.Length);
    return File(ms, "application/pdf");
}
```

The third code example approach seems promising for concatenating files by their bytes, but MemoryStream doesn't appear to work when writing bytes to it, as opposed to initializing the stream with the bytes (as in example 2.)

I think I remember reading that PDF data isn't stored as bytes?
What is happening here that would cause example 2 to work (for a single PDF), but example 3 (which should be doing the same thing), doesn't work for even a single PDF?

Thank you for your help,

Matthew

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.write(v=vs.110).aspx

> If the write operation is successful, the current position within the
>   stream is advanced by the number of bytes written.

```
public ActionResult PrintInvoice(string invoiceNumber)
{
    string fileloc = GetInvoiceFileLocation(invoiceNumber);
    fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(fileloc);
    ms = new MemoryStream();
    ms.Write(fileBytes, 0, fileBytes.Length);

    ms.Position = 0;    

    return File(ms, "application/pdf");
}
```